# Bash script echo is performing a strange substitution

Tags: bash, shell, glob, substitution

Realizing bash is very picky about double quotes, single quotes, brackets etc. -- I ran across a strange behavior today and can't explain it.  The problem itself is easy to avoid but I don't understand the cause.  I'm interested to understand WHY this happened just to improve my bash knowledge.

Here is a shortened example -- contents of file test.sh:

```
msg="Usage: command password [dbhost] [database] [user] [query] [filetag]"
echo $msg
```

Then run:

```
sh test.sh
```

I expected the output would be:

```
Usage: command password [dbhost] [database] [user] [query] [filetag]
```

However what I got was:

```
Usage: command password [dbhost] [database] [user] y [filetag]
```

If I change the word "query" to "querx", that part of the output becomes "x".

If I change the word "query" to "xuery", that part of the output becomes "x y".

If I change the word "query" to "xuerx", that part of the output becomes "x x".

There are no local or environment variables with names like query, querx etc.

This is on RedHat.  Any ideas?

Comment: Never ever ever use unquoted variables (unless you are bash guru and can kill all processes and reformat the root filesystem in 3 special characters and no letters). Change this to `echo "$msg"`.

Comment: I think it's trying to match files in your directory.  Do you have files or directories named 'x' or 'y'?

Comment: The immediate reason of that failure is having certain files with one-letter names in your current directory. And `[word]` *matches* one or more of them. Don't trust me, go to an empty directory and try again, then add one-letter files and see what changes.

Comment: You are correct, the directory where I was testing has files named "x" and "y".  What is it about the construct "[query]" that would cause these file names to be matched / expanded in this way?

Comment: `[abc]` is a *glob* that matches either `a` or `b` or `c`. It is defined to be this way. You can combine this construct with other globs like `*` and `?` and plin characters of course, to get more useful patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of [*word expansions* for a Bourne compatible shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06) is

1. Tilde Expansion
2. Parameter Expansion
3. Command Substitution
4. Arithmetic Expansion
5. Field Splitting
6. Pathname Expansion
7. Quote Removal

So after parameter expansion for `$msg`, the pathname expansion finds `[query]` which looks for a file called `q`, `u`, `e`, `r` or `y`. You have a file named `y`, right?

Note that this behavior depends on the setting of the `f` option. With `set -f` the pathname expansion is not performed, while with `set +f` it is.

Of course you could double quote the echo arg as well, since pathname expansion is not performed on quoted words.